# Compile node-5.1.0 in CentOS 6.7 lacks of g++ 4.8+

Tags: centos, configuration, gcc, g++, compilation

I'm trying to compile [node-5.1.0](https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.1.0/node-v5.1.0.tar.gz) in CentOS 6.7 but is asking for **g++ 4.8** or above.

```
[root@ws node-v5.1.0]# ./configure
WARNING: C++ compiler too old, need g++ 4.8 or clang++ 3.4 (CXX=g++)
...
```

First I've installed "Development Tools":

```
[root@ws node-v5.1.0]# yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

After I check `g++` version:

```
[root@ws node-v5.1.0]# g++ -v
...
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC)
```

Though that version isn't enough then I perform a little research and found a *possible* way to install/upgrade `g++`. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32433483/719427t) and I followed every step:

```
[root@ws node-v5.1.0]# wget http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/devtools-2.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/devtools-2.repo

[root@ws node-v5.1.0]# yum install devtoolset-2-gcc devtoolset-2-binutils

[root@ws node-v5.1.0]# /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15
...
```

I tried the same command again for compile NodeJS:

```
[root@ws node-v5.1.0]# ./configure
WARNING: C++ compiler too old, need g++ 4.8 or clang++ 3.4 (CXX=g++)
```

But as you can see I got the same error regarding g++ version which make me ask:

- how can I pass new installed `gcc` version to `./configure`?
- there is any other way to use or set that version as default?

*Note:* by version I mean the one at `/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc` if it's complete secure to change to that one

**Update**

After post the question I've found [this](https://superuser.com/a/542091/309325) and follow the same steps:

```
[root@ws node-v5.1.0]# export CC=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc
[root@ws node-v5.1.0]# export CPP=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/cpp
[root@ws node-v5.1.0]# export CXX=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/c++
```

But results is the same:

```
[root@ws node-v5.1.0]# ./configure
WARNING: C++ compiler too old, need g++ 4.8 or clang++ 3.4 (CXX=g++)
```

Comment: Why do you need to compile node? how about using binaries?

Comment: @risyasin I can use binaries for sure by downloading them and place somewhere but I think this is not the recommended/right way, if you have some docs about this please share with me but I don't know how to get this working after use binaries

Comment: Just download the binaries x64 or 86 which is your platform. extract into /usr. so you will have 2 executable in /usr/bin. node & npm. I really don't think it will make a difference compiling vs using precompiled ones. in your case you can even break dependencies of other packages in your system.

Comment: You don't need compiling unless you have changed the nodejs sources or the libraries such as openssl. if you are using distro provided libraries without changing their sources. then you really do not need it.

Answer (score 1):

- update dev3 and enable
  -scl enable devtoolset-3 bash
  -./configure
- make sure from nodjs dir

Answer (score 1):

Import CERN's GPG key:

`sudo rpm --import http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/5x/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEYs/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern`

Save repository information as `/etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-devtoolset.repo` on your system:

`wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-devtoolset.repo http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6-devtoolset.repo`
Install:

`sudo yum install devtoolset-2`

Enable the environment:

`scl enable devtoolset-2 bash`

Test the environment:

`$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
...`

`$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
...`

Extracted from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/stephenturner/e3bc5cfacc2dc67eca8b).